# Can sealert display the full command of a denied access request?

Tags: selinux

I am managing a Red Hat Enterprise 5 system using [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/). Something within sequence of configuration commands is generating selinux alerts such as:

```
SELinux is preventing iptables (iptables_t) "read" to /superhome/dir (user_home_dir_t).
```

However when I run "sealert -l", it seems I only see partial information:

```
...snip...

Additional Information:

Source Context                root:system_r:iptables_t
Target Context                system_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t
Target Objects                /superhome/redacted [ dir ]
Source                        iptables
Source Path                   /sbin/iptables
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          redacted.host.name
Source RPM Packages           iptables-1.3.5-5.3.el5_4.1
Target RPM Packages        
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-2.4.6-316.el5
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
MLS Enabled                   True
Enforcing Mode                Permissive
Plugin Name                   catchall_file
Host Name                     redacted.host.name
Platform                      Linux redacted.host.name 2.6.18-274.el5 #1 SMP
                              Fri Jul 8 17:36:59 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   17
First Seen                    Tue Jul 31 11:16:38 2012
Last Seen                     Tue Jul 31 18:46:35 2012
Local ID                      6c58ff2c-6cab-4db0-b047-896d6adc8e0f
Line Numbers               

Raw Audit Messages         

host=redacted.host.name type=AVC msg=audit(1343774795.973:33819): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=26444 comm="iptables" path="/superhome/redacted" dev=dm-0 ino=27656194 scontext=root:system_r:iptables_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 tclass=dir

host=redacted.host.name type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1343774795.973:33819): arch=c000003e syscall=59 success=yes exit=0 a0=1ec6c5a0 a1=1ec28360 a2=1ec2b540 a3=8 items=0 ppid=26435 pid=26444 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=1500 comm="iptables" exe="/sbin/iptables" subj=root:system_r:iptables_t:s0 key=(null)
```

Presumably the "Source" command had additional arguments (**Note**: the exact directory name  below "/superhome", and the hostname have been redacted). Is there any way to find out the arguments and/or the full command?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the additional info.

I did quite a bit of looking into this, and couldn't find any way to reproduce this issue.

I found that iptables doesn't actually have any command line options that would cause it to read a user-supplied file. Nor does its SELinux reference policy define any need to read arbitrary files.

My suspicion at this point is that some files on your target system are mislabeled. This could happen if, for instance, someone was editing a copy of iptables' configuration file in a user home directory and moved it to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` instead of copying it. Moving a file preserves its SELinux context, and so it would have the wrong context at its destination. Copying a file creates the new file with the default context for the new location, which is almost always the correct context.

If it is mislabeled files, then running `restorecon` should fix it right up. To be sure, I'd just relabel the whole filesystem. You can do this without rebooting by running:

```
restorecon -r -vv /
```

Or you can just relabel files likely to be affected:

```
restorecon -r -vv /etc
```

The -r option makes it recurse, and -vv makes it extra verbose.

It's also possible that a file that iptables wants to read is symlinked to a file in a user's home directory. In the current reference policy, iptables has access to read/write `/etc/sysconfig/ip6?tables.*`.

One final note: It appears your system has SELinux in permissive mode. This means that these events are logged, but not actually denied. You can restore enforcing mode by running `setenforce 1`. Then watch to see what breaks. :)